# Do SQL Server Transaction Logs get 'locked' when there is a non-zero log_reuse_wait?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

**Scenario:**

I have an application attempting to write to a SQL Server DB, and I'm getting the message:

*The transaction log for database 'DB_NAME' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases*

However, I see that there is plenty of space on the drive for the transaction log to be written and autogrowth is on.  So from SQL Management Studio, I issue:

```
select name,
    log_reuse_wait,
    log_reuse_wait_desc
  from sys.databases 
  where name = 'DB_NAME'
```

and can see that the log_reuse_wait is '3'.

**Question:**

Do SQL Server transaction logs get 'locked' in any way when this wait is in place?

Note that this is set to 'Simple' recover model.  Please let me know if there is more information I need to provide to make this a complete question.

Comment: Just curious what the _desc field says?

Comment: Active Backup or Restore

Comment: Going on a limb, but was the DB left in restoring state??? I think dba.SE is a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be of help.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190925.aspx

The log reuse wait you are encountering indicates that there is a backup in progress.
Even in simple recovery, a full database backup has to include part of the transaction log.